# Creating new entity related with extisting one

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to figure it out how to do this proper way. Let's say I have entity `Employee` like that:

```
@Entity
public class EmployeeEntity{

   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String username;
   private String password;
   private List<AddressEntity> addresses;
   private DepartmentEntity department;

}
```

Now let's say some `AddressEntity` and `DepartmentEntity` are already created so I just want to point it. Controller would look like this:

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController{

   @Autowired
   private EmployeeService;

   @PostMapping
   public EmployeeDto createEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeDto employee){
      return employeeService.createEmployee(employee);
   }
}
```

And DTO:

```
public class EmployeeDto{
   private Long id;
   private String username;
   private String password;
   private List<AddressDto> addresses;
   // private List<Long> addressesIds;
   private DepartmentDto department; 
   // private Long departmentId;
}
```

So what bothers me is **how properly transfer data from request to service layer and to response**.

- should DTO be object 1:1 same like entity?
- or with additional values, like ids of others related objects?
- or DTO is just concept and as well I can use custom request/response for every occasion? This would be handy but is it the way it should be done? There would be plenty of one-case-use classes.

Crating new entity is first problem but how about updating? If I would like to update just `Employee` username, I shouldn`t pass all rest of the objects so ids maybe? And it should be custom `UpdateEmployeeRequest` with only updatable fields or DTO with all data like `password`?

Sorry if I messed up a little. Too much new knowledge and I feel like I go round and round like a child in the fog...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should DTO be object 1:1 same like entity? or with additional values, like ids of others related objects?

Not necessary. DTOs are mostly to pass data to view layer. You can wrap data from multiple entities and send in one DTO to view.

> or DTO is just concept and as well I can use custom request/response for every occasion? This would be handy but is it the way it should be done? There would be plenty of one-case-use classes.

Yes. It is like custom request/response for every occasion (data transfer to view and from view).

> Crating new entity is first problem but how about updating? If I would like to update just Employee username, I shouldn`t pass all rest of the objects so ids maybe? And it should be custom UpdateEmployeeRequest with only updatable fields or DTO with all data like password?

Pass the required minimum fields and use same DTO on Create/Update (Id with field to update on update and other fields on Create).

Example dto for create:

```
   username : "some user",
   password : "some password",
   ... other fields
```

Example JSON for update username:

```
id: 1,
username : "some user",
```